# Display the actual number of questions on the tag page

Tags: feature-request, design, tags-page

On the main tag page a tag can have a number to the right or not. If there is no number to the right then this means that there are either 1 or 0 questions tagged with this tag *or* that it is a synonym; this is confusing and sometimes annoying.

Can it be changed to remove those tags that have 0 questions, and which are not synonyms, and place a number by the tags that have one? Like this (poor) mock-up:

> [image: crocodiles like bamboo]

This leaves a clear delineation between tags with questions, tags without questions and synonyms.

I'm guessing that the ones with 0 questions attached might still be around because they haven't been "deleted" yet. If it's difficult/unwanted to remove these can we have a `x 1` by the tags that do have questions and a method of identifying synonyms so people can differentiate between the three possibilities.

Comment: The ones that have 0 questions are usually synonyms that redirect to a different tag.

Comment: @animuson @(cc OP) Maybe mark those with `x S` or something.

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe, but I can't find it...

Comment: In my world they're the ones that have been removed from all questions @animuson :-). Point taken though; fixing...

Comment: I was a little surprised myself @Charles; but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Found the dupe! @ben, feel free to add that mockup in there it's better than nothing. ;)

Comment: Thanks @ShaWizDowArd; done.

Comment: @ben meant in the question to make it clearer but answer is also good plus more rep for you. ;)

Comment: I can ask a mod to mark it as CW @sha :-); I put it as an answer because the q was synonyms and I wanted to suggest more.

Comment: @ben we can still mark answers as CW. :D (but honestly, it's a good suggestion so deserve some rep :))